# Unnecessary return methods for class attributes

Tags: python

I've noticed that every once in a while, someone will write a class in python along these lines

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def some_method(self):
        # Do stuff to self.x

    def get_results(self):
        return self.x
```

My question is concerning the `get_results` method, which seems superfluous to me since `self.x` can be accessed directly with `instance_name.x`. Is there a reason why including a method like this would be necessary/preferable? Is it an artifact of a programmer's experience with other languages?

Comment: This is an opinion, so I'm not putting it as an answer, but, yes, I think this is due to experience with other languages like Java. As the saying goes, you can write FORTRAN in any language.

Comment: You asked a slightly different question, but the answer to your question, and other strongly related discussion is covered in great detail in the above link.